# Read file name from FreeBSD vnode

Tags: c, freebsd

I'm trying to fetch file name from FreeBSD vnode structure. I read vnode manual and I know that this structure represents any of file activity in system (opened files, directories, etc).

What I've got in my code is pointer to vnode structure and access to FreeBSD memory image. But the problem is that I cannot use any kind of system API: neither user-space nor kernel-space. To be more precisely I'm writing some kind of extension to Lauterbach HW debugger. This debugger allows me to read debug symbols from kernel, read 32-bit, 16-bit and 8-bit values from memory.

As far as I know there are some functions like vn_fullpath() which allow to fetch file name from vnode structure. I could analyse them and try to reimplement them in my code, but they are using filesystem cache and I'd like to avoid using cache and read the file name directly from filesystem or filesystem agnostic system layer.

I analysed the vnode structure and unfortunately I didn't find any usable information how to get file name from vnode. Any suggestions how to go through kernel structures to get it?

Comment: It sounds like vnodes ***don't have*** filenames or paths. That's why vn_fullpath has to guess (according to its man page). Do you want to guess, or do you want the actual pathname? Because you cannot get the actual pathname.

Comment: I need only file name, not whole path.

Comment: I don't know about FreeBSD, but on Linux, files don't have names, so you would still have to guess. Do you want to guess?